# ASP.NET MVC stops executing actions when runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=false

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

When I set `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=false` to increase MVC performance the MVC stops executing Actions like `[ActionName("membership.asp")]`. I get `404` error on `IIS7.5`.
Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution by myself. Just need to add extension to web.config file which should be handled by MVC.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="ClassicASP" path="*.asp" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="File" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
```